# How to test Auto logout using selenium in java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a web application which logs off automatically when remained idle for sometime. I tried using the following code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), 300);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("logout.button")));
```

This just gives `TimeOutException` after 5 minutes. Any idea how to implement?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will timeout in 5 minutes because you have given 300 seconds. Instead of searching for logout button why not search fro log in button.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), 300);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("login.button")));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In simple way You can make use **sleep** for that idle amount of time(In
   specification document they will mentioned the auto 'logout' time)
2. Then check for the 'login' or some elemnet which will appear
   after 'logout'

   Note: You used explicit wait of 300 second, that's what it gives "TimeOutException after 5 minutes"

Comment: It doesn't work. Actually when i run the test in the webdriver's instance of firefox it doesn't logout ever automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a timer, then put that in a loop waiting until there is no exception or the timer runs out (failing the test in this case).

You also should check all default implicit wait times either on your infrastructure or your test framework, there may be something that timeouts all waits before reaching a certain threshold.

Otherwise, I assume that you're testing a web app that has a javascript timer which timeout's at 5 min if there is no activity. Could you not better alter that waiting time for this test so that the timeout happens earlier ? hanging a thread 5min for a single test seems rather long.